# date displaying 31st December 1969

Tags: php, date

This is probably very simple indeed, I've looked around and can't see what I have wrong.

I have a field in my table called EVENT_DATES stored as a date, and an example of the data stored in one row is 2014-02-14

When I use the following php code to show that date as 14th February 2014, I get 31st December 1969.

```
<?php echo date('jS F Y',strtotime($row_THISMONTH['EVENT_DATES'])); ?>
```

Any thoughts on how I can correct this?

Comment: wow - you are right, I am such an idiot, I had changed the query name and forgotten to change it in my php. I am having one of those days! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you describe would typically occur when you pass an empty value to `strtotime()` (or a value that is not a date that it can recognize).

Make sure that `$row_THISMONTH['EVENT_DATES']` actually contains a value. Use `echo()` to output and debug it.